# Функция js не выполняет запрос к файлу .php

Tags: php, javascript, html

По нажатию кнопки вызывается функция `js` и происходит вызов `php` файла.
Но файл `php` не вызывается.
Что я делаю не так?

Код **html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Table</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>
     function clients()
     {
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getclients.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
     }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button type="submit" name="button" onClick="clients()">Загрузить данные</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Код **getclients.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   table {
     width: 100%;
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   table, td, th{
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 5px;
   }
   th {text-align: left;}
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <?php
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost:3306','root','1234','mydatabase');
   if (!$con){
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));
   }
   $select = mysql_select_db(mydatabase);
   $sql="SELECT * FROM clients";
   $query = mysql_query($sql,$con);
   echo "<table> <tr> <th>Email</th> </tr>";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";
  mysql_close($con);
  mysql_free_result($query);
  ?>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Во первых - покажите ваш  `xmlhttp`, это нативный `XMLHttpRequest`? Во вторых - что значит не вызывается? Нет запроса? Не приходят данные? Или вы хотите их как то обработать и не знаете как?

Comment: @endless, `mysql_...` это устаревший и небезопасный драйвер, используйте `PDO` или `mysqli`

Comment: Даже если предположить, что весь ваш код работает, вы **не используете** полученный от сервера ответ. Какой реакции от JS скрипта вы ждете?

Comment: @stckvrw подскажите, где можно посмотреть про правильное использование PDO и SQLi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в РНР-обработчике вместо `mysql_...` использовать PDO-драйвер тогда код обработчика следующий (только РНР, не нужно никаких хтмл-тегов !!!):

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=localhost', 'root', '1234');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `clients`";
$array = array();
foreach($pdo->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
    $array[] = $row['email']."|".$row['user'];
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

а код хтмл-страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
table {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, td, th{
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
}
th {text-align: left;}
</style>
<script>
function clients()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","getclients.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onload = function(data) {
        var dataAsArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        arrayWithCommas = [];
        for (i = 0; i < dataAsArray.length; i++) {
            var parts = dataAsArray[i].split('|');
            var email = parts[0];
            var user = parts[1];
            arrayWithCommas.push("<tr><th>Email</th><th>User</th></tr><tr><td>"+email+"</td><td>"+user+"</td></tr>");
        }
        tableHTML = [];
        tableHTML.push(arrayWithCommas.join(""));
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = tableHTML;
    }
    xmlhttp.onerror = function(data) {
        console.log('Error with status '+this.status);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="submit" name="button" onClick="clients()">Загрузить данные</button>
    <table id="table"><table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: ответ из консоли]

это во-первых.

Во-вторых. Если Вы хотите экспериментировать с локальными файлами - вам нужен локальный вэб-сервер, localhost, грубо говоря. Потому что
[image: ответ из консоли]

И вот, после всех мытарств, установив сервер и изменив код на

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/getclients.php', true);
xhr.send();
```

мы получаем ответ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что отображается он лишь во вкладке ответов, пустые поля, ясное дело, из-за отсутствия у меня вашей базы данных. Но запрос отрабатывает, ответ приходит.

Подытожим.

1. Вам нужно отправлять запрос на сервер в сети (или локальный).
2. Вам нужно использовать нативный объект XMLHttpRequest или проверить
   подключение используемой Вами библиотеки, где объявлен объект
   xmlhttp.
3. Я ничего не говорю про php, хотя там тоже можно кое-что поменять ;)

Удачных исследований :)